# Spam Comments from Anonymous Users

Tags: wordpress, spam, spam-prevention

So we can't figure this out for the life of us.

Comments are only allowed if they register and they aren't registered, they are all anonymous. I'm not talking one or two here, I'm talking 60+ in one day & I don't get a lot of traffic.

We thought it was the Profile Builder plugin b/c the spam comments stopped when I deactivated it, but then they started coming back. I deactivated again & again they came back.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if u want to prevent spam comment
then go on wordpress dashboard
Setting<Discussion<Other Comment Setting section
and tick on "Users must be registered and logged in to comment".
and in same bottom go on "Before a comment appears" setting and tick on " Comment must be manually approved".

Thanks

Comment: You didn't read what we said. That is already checked off in WP.